# File upload/download using Spring and Jackrabbit

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jackrabbit, jcr

My application requires upload/download files using Jackrabbit RMI-repository.
I am using Spring 3.1, Tomcat 6, PostgreSQL 9. So which version of Jackrabbit is compatible with my current application? Also I am confused about how to go with this work.
I am not expecting detail level coding I just want to know what structure should I follow?
Like: I have running application with above specifications now

- How to integrate Jackrabbit what configuration should I use.
- I want to store data into database (PostgreSQL) so what is configuration should I follow?

Is there any link or sample project which I can refer?
Please help I really stuck here from long time.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Apache Jackrabbit (2.5.2 or 2.4.3) should be compatible as we use it in Silverpeas.
Connecting through RMI is not recommended by the Jackrabbit team :

> Warning: The current JCR-RMI library is designed for simplicity, not performance. You will probably experience major performance issues if you try running any non-trivial applications on top of JCR-RMI ([Jackrabbit documentation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/repository-server-howto.html)).

You can take a look at [our code](https://github.com/ehsavoie/Silverpeas-Core/blob/feature_82/web-core/src/main/java/org/silverpeas/attachment/web/SimpleDocumentResourceCreator.java) that creates document (file + metadata) but in a servlet not in Spring MVC. Since after the upload we use the standard JCR API all should be the same after you got a Repository from your rmi URL with JcrUtils.